# Integrating Next JS SSR Application with WordPress for SEO Benefits: Feasibility, Challenges, and Alternatives?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, seo, wordpress-gutenberg, headless

"I have a Next.js application that relies on server-side rendering (SSR) and want to integrate it with a WordPress website for SEO benefits. Is it technically feasible to wrap my Next.js code within a traditional Gutenberg-style WordPress theme, and what are the potential challenges, complexities, and alternatives I should consider for this integration?"

Comment: Stackoverflow is more about helping you on things you're stuck on in code. What have you tried? What are the issues you faced?

Comment: @Vivick I have tried to load my next.js website's codes in a Wordpress custom theme using Wp-Scripts. But it's not loading. I am getting error on process.env lines and i am suspecting this issues are causing because i am running worpress on apache2/nginx, but my next.js code needs differenet enviroment.

When i am trying to load something simpler react codes it's loading though.

Comment: @ShahidFahad You can't put it inside wordpress directories. These SPA's are taking the information from wp API and do everything else custom. These applications are also called DECOUPLED for that very reason. That said, WP can help you as CMS and not with SEO, in that very setting.

Comment: @billybadass is there any other way to achieve this? Can it be done with guttenberg?

Comment: You can follow good SEO practices and facilitate that through wordpress. Example: you have a meta-description field inside the page (wordpress), you push that to API and then you embed it to your SPA.